# Laravel can't write to app/storage/views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a working website, but from time to time it gets error 500 and it says:

> file_put_contents(/webserver/app/storage/views/c2719e58403973c7f90aef11e3d73aaa):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied (View:
>   some.actual.view.blade.php)

The thing is that the permissions are correct (www-data is the owner of the folder and its children), since it's able to write for some (undefined time) and this error appears.

I think it might be a problem with space? number of files in directory? When I clear the folder I don't get this error.

PS: I ran the `ls -l` command before deleting everything from the folder. Few of the files were owned by `root`. How can they be owned by `root`? Does that mean that laravel was executed by the `root`?

Comment: Do you run any artisan command under `root` user?

Comment: I have this same problem where I would keep having to do **chmod -R** every once in a while. Probably useful to say whether you are using vagrant/homestead or running directly off your own machine.

Comment: Yep, that was it! I figured it out while editing the question. You can add it as answer and I will accept it. I was running `composer update` wchich triggers re-compiling the views.

Comment: offtopic: @Amarnasan, http://www.nerdtests.com/images/ft/nq/4fbf3d9fe6.gif :P

Comment: offtopic: Oh, you're a nerd goddess!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you run some artisan command under root user and that created files as root which may not be modified.